# Troubleshooting springboot locking issues

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm a DB guy with some app experience. I do not have a code sample so hoping someone with springboot experience can shed light on this.

We have Java code using springboot to select single rows out of the database all day (for a web  application)

We have a morning process which needs to merge into the same table. Target table has 1.3 million rows. Source table has between 8k to 16k rows

Under normal circumstances this merge is complete in under five minutes or so

However in 3 out of 14 runs we have an issue where this activity collides with springboot select activity

Note that all tables are indexes, queries optmised etc.

What confuses me is that springboot is running a `select` query, however the error returned is

> CannotAcquireLockException

When I check the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/CannotAcquireLockException.html) it says

> Exception thrown on failure to acquire a lock during an update, for example during a "select for update" statement.

**But this is not an update statement**

As far as I know it is not a SELECT FOR UPDATE statement.

I'm not too sharp on the Java code but I can see this code fragment:

(Sorry for screenshot I'll come back and convert to code if anyone shows any interest)

[image]

Is `CrudRepository` automatically assuming this is write query and needlessly applying locks? can anyone tell me what to look for to confirm this query is set to read only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause was that the springboot queries were using the wrong data type for a parameter, making the select queries non sargable, in turn requiring a table scan (rather than utilising the index)..... lots and lots of table scans that were hidden by scaling the server up to a huge core count. After we fixed the parameter data type in the query to match the search fields data type, db activity went waaaaaaay down and the problem disappeared. AFAIK the CannotAcquireLockException was a legitimate message - it couldn't actually acquire a shared lock it was simply too busy doing table scans and dealing with the data merge.

Comment: This problem is very interesting. Can I ask how much time does the other process take when it actually success?

Comment: The "other process" is fast, like less than seconds, but it happens many many times a second. (it's a web page under high usage)